# How to embed custom atoms(tweets/video/fb post) inside redactor editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, redactor, redactor.js

I have redactor 10, want to achieve following functionality using redactor plugin:-

User can insert atoms(tweets/video/fb post) inside redactor editor by clicking on some link. What i want is I should only insert a custom html tag for atom inside redactor.

eg:- `<embed type="tweet" id="xxxx"></embed>` and it should display an image of twitter logo inside redactor html view.

Similarly for `<embed type="fb" id="xxxx"></embed>` it should display fb logo.

Anyone has ideas regarding how to do it?

Comment: Did you ever work out how to do this? Looking to achieve similar or at least just allow it through pasted html...

Comment: Yes in fact, we have created templates which contains data in their attributes (eg data-id="xxx"). While saving data in database, we parse the template, get the data attribute and create embed tags on that.